# Difficulties to retrieve values from Junction object in apex

Tags: apex, trigger, before-trigger, code

**Requirement**

I have 2 objects(**sale_product**,**sales_Product_parts**) 
one product can have many parts and one part can be assign to many product)
i have created juntion object to achieve this.

**My requirement is**

On update of product i need to check product_part and if values in avialable_unit is 0 then throw error and dont save record

else if unit available more than 0 then do minus 1 from avialable unit for that perticular record.

I have started writing code, but stuck dont understand how to progress to achieve these 2 goals:

1. Error throw if available_Unit =0
2. minus 1 from available unit from product_part record.

Code:

```
public class SalesPartHandler {
    public static void checkSalesPart(list<sales_product__c>ProdList) {
        set<id>productId =new set<id>();
        for(sales_product__c pr:ProdList) {
            productId.add(pr.id);
        }
        list<Product_part_join__c> salesp = new list<Product_part_join__c>([
            select id,name,Sales_Product__r.id,Sales_Product_Part__r.name,Sales_Product_Part__r.id
            from Product_part_join__c
            where Sales_Product__r.id in :productId
            and Sales_Product_Part__r.Available_units__c=0
        ]);
        system.debug('salesp==>'+salesp);
        Map<id,List<string>> getprodMap = new map<id,List<string>>();
        list<string> names =new list<string>();
```

Comment: What's the error you're getting.And could you please share your logs?

Comment: no i am not able to proceed further.not able to build logic further

Answer (score 1):

Rearrange the code to something like this:

```
Sales_Product_Part__c[] updates = new Sales_Product_Part__c[] {};
for (Product_part_join__c ppj = [
        select
            id,
            name,
            Sales_Product__r.id,
            Sales_Product_Part__r.name,
            Sales_Product_Part__r.id,
            Sales_Product_Part__r.Available_units__c
        from Product_part_join__c
        where Sales_Product__r.id in :productId
        ]) {
    if (ppj.Sales_Product_Part__r.Available_units__c > 0) {
        updates.add(new Sales_Product_Part__c(
            Id = ppj.Sales_Product_Part__r.id,
            Available_units__c = ppj.Sales_Product_Part__r.Available_units__c - 1
        ));
    } else {
        ppj.addError('***Error Message ****');
    }
}
update updates;
```

Comment: You beat me in a few seconds.